# Detect host of in a url with a subdomain

Tags: javascript, subdomain

if there are a bunch of URL's:

- `sub1.sub.example.com`
- `sub2.sub.example.com`
- `sub3.sub.example.com`
- `sub4.sub.example.com`
- etc.

How can I detect if the hostname is `something.sub.example.com`?

What I tried, which does not work:

```
if (window.location.hostname == "*.sub.example.com") {
  //actions 
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use either [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) or [`string.endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can use `String#endsWith` to do exactly what you want:

```
if (window.location.hostname.endswith(".sub.example.com")) { . . . }
```

As pointed out by Jake Holzinger in the comments, IE does not support `String#endsWith`. A simple regex solution which would have better compatibility would

```
// This is a Regular Expression literal meaning
// a string ending with ".sub.example.com" (case-insensitive)
var regexSubdomainPattern = /\.sub\.example\.com$/ig;
if (regexSubdomainPattern.test(window.location.hostname)) { . . . }
```

Comment: `String.prototype.endsWith` is not available in IE, if IE is a target platform this should be implemented using `String.prototype.indexOf`, or a polyfill/utility library.

Comment: Great point. Regex would probably be the best option then if compatibility is a focus.

Answer (score 0):

The `String (object) Prototype` contains a handy method called `includes()`

So you can take any string argument you have and use the following code

```js
function ddcc(what){ // ddcc - domain dot com check
  return what.includes('sub.example.com');
}

var test = 'wwww.madeup.sub.example.com';
console.log(ddcc(test));

// so in practice - if ddcc(window.location.hostname) { .. } will do the trick
```

Should serve you just fine.

---

**EDIT:** If you insist on your `.hostname` ending with `sub.example.com` and nothing else then:

```js
function ddcc(what) { // ddcc - domain dot com check
  return what.includes('sub.example.com') ?
    what.substring(what.indexOf('sub.example.com'), what.length) === 'sub.example.com' :
    false;
}

var test = 'madeup.sub.example.com.fakelink';
console.log(ddcc(test));
```

As you can see, I appended `.fakelink` to our `test` variable. Although it includes `sub.example.com` it returns as `false` nonetheless.